# Adding 2 arraylists to one 2 dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to add two arraylists to a 2 dimensional array but I am coming across a problem. If I fill the array manually, shown in the code below as array arr1, and bind this array to a chart, the chart displays as expected. However, when I add the two arraylists to the array using a for loop and bind this array to a chart, it does not display as expected.

My Code:

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2012, 10, 1);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2012, 11, 2);
DateTime date3 = new DateTime(2012, 12, 3);
DateTime date4 = new DateTime(2013, 01, 4);
DateTime date5 = new DateTime(2013, 02, 8);

//Create time arraylist
ArrayList al1 = new ArrayList();
al1.Add(date1);
al1.Add(date2);
al1.Add(date3);
al1.Add(date4);
al1.Add(date5);

int int1 = 9;
int int2 = 15;
int int3 = 20;
int int4 = 13;
int int5 = 17;

//Create int arraylist
ArrayList al2 = new ArrayList();
al2.Add(int1);
al2.Add(int2);
al2.Add(int3);
al2.Add(int4);
al2.Add(int5);

//Tester 2D array
Object[,] arr1 = new Object[,] { {date1, int1}, {date2, int2}, {date3, int3}, {date4,int4}, {date5, int5} };

//Create 2D array
Object[,] arr = new Object[2, al2.Count];

for (int k = 0; k <al2.Count; k++)
        {
            arr[0, k] = al1[k];
            arr[1, k] = al2[k];
        }

Data d1 = new Data(arr);

Series s1 = new Series { Name = "Series 1", Data=d1};

DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart");

chart.SetXAxis(new XAxis
{
Type = AxisTypes.Datetime
});

chart.SetSeries(s1);

ltrChart.Text = chart.ToHtmlString();
```

Is my problem with in the adding of the arraylists to the array or is it something within dotnet highcharts?

Comment: And what are the two results. What is the expected and what is the actual result?

Comment: The expected results is a line graph of time against int,  { {1/10/2012, 9} {2/11/2012, 15} etc }, which is what I get when I use the arr1 array. The result when I use arr array is just two points on the graph, { {1/1/1970, 15}, {30/09/2012, 131581440000} }

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s7p4.html).

Comment: unless you are stuck pre .Net 2.0, don't use `ArrayList`, if "HighCharts" only accepts a multidimensional `ArrayList` don't use "HighCharts".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop creates a different array, because you mixed up the dimensions. Do it this way:

```
Object[,] arr = new Object[al2.Count, 2];

for (int k = 0; k < al2.Count; k++)
{
    arr[k, 0] = al1[k];
    arr[k, 1] = al2[k];
}
```

Comment: You could also check for al1.Count == al2.Count, else it could throw an exception.

Comment: @fabigler He fills them manually in the code, how could they have different sizes? And even if he didn't, if they do, there is a mistake somewhere else. Fix that then.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try a `List<KeyValuePair<Date,int>>` and fill your 2D array from there, or if the dates are unique, a `Dictionary<Date, int>`